# What is a viable Azure host for long running Python API Endpoint?

Tags: python, .net, azure, api, cloud

I have a Python script that takes 20 minutes to run. I need to be able to trigger this script via my Azure .NET application.

I am looking for a possible cloud based host to help me do this. Preferably Azure, but open to other options.

I have tried the following Options:

1. Azure Functions

Assessment: Found too many limitations on code structure (e.g. have to organize Python files in certain way)

2. Azure Web App

Assessment: Works to create an endpoint but has timeout issues for long requests

3. Azure Virtual Machine (VM)

Assessment: I simulated a trigger by scheduling the script frequently on the VM. This is not a bad solution but not ideal either

What other viable options exist?

Comment: Either you restructure your program and send out HTTP 201 or 202 for long requests or you host it on a VPS.

Answer (score 0):

You can also choose to use `Azure Web Jobs` to serve this purpose.

It has a setting to specify idle time (`WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT`):

[image]

*The value must be in **seconds**, example 3600 which means the idle time before it times out is 1 hour. Note that this option will affect all scheduled web jobs either under web app or azure function.*

Reference: https://jtabuloc.wordpress.com/2018/06/05/how-to-avoid-azure-webjob-idle-timeout-exception/